# Jenkins access private BitBucket repo over SSH

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins, bitbucket

I'm having trouble getting Jenkins to clone a git repository on BitBucket via SSH. It's failing with the following message:

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test
[ssh-agent] Using credentials git (git@bitbucket.org:<user>/<repo>.git)
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Java/JNR ssh-agent
[ssh-agent] Started.
Checkout:test / /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@2b619bca
Using strategy: Default
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from origin
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch -t origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

#### Steps taken

- Create an SSH keypair
- Add the public key as a deployment key for the repository on BitBucket
- Install the SSH key and username (have tried both 'git' and my BB account name) in the Jenkins Credentials manager plugin
- Attempt to clone the repository in the build using a URL in form of

  `git@bitbucket.org:<user>/<repo>.git`

I've also tried not using the credentials manager and manually installing the keys in `/var/log/jenkins/.ssh/`, but to no avail.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the clone working from command line? It is possible that Jenkins is running as user "jenkins" which might be different from the user which you are trying to clone... Jenkins must be running as the user "user" for which you uploaded the keys...

Comment: Actually, no - it turned out to be a firewall issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: FWIW copying the keys from my user account to `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh` helped me with similar issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @user1562655 suggested out, the clone was failing due to another issue -- in this case the firewall was blocking outgoing ssh on port 22.

The fix was to use port 443 (as the server allows this), and a different BitBucket URL:

```
ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/<user>/<repo>.git
```

…instead of

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org:<user>/<repo>.git
```

More info on the scheme is available here:

[UsetheSSHprotocolwithBitbucket-SSHonPort443](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket#UsetheSSHprotocolwithBitbucket-SSHonPort443)

Comment: Also, to clarify: the SSH credentials plugin /was/ working to supply the relevant key to the builder; there's no need to manually install it in jenkins` `~/.ssh`.

Comment: The Atlassian documentation is now located here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html

Comment: also... not `.git`... end it with a `/`. So example: `ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/<user>/<repo>/`

Comment: @user2424511 The provided link has died

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and actually this solution helped me out:

```
vim ~/.ssh/config
```

Add these lines and save it.

```
Host github.com
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    Port 443

Host bitbucket.org
    Hostname  altssh.bitbucket.org
    Port  443
```

taken from https://gist.github.com/goddoe/5692bfc3cdc374d918a87882963edf36